# Search an Txt file for a string by keyword using a JTextfield and print out the whole string

Tags: java, swing, search, arraylist, jtextfield

I added some text to an array and stored it in a txt file. Now I need to search the txt file by an ID using a `JTextfield` and output the corresponding string items from the file to the `JFrame`.

```
public class search implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evtSeacrh) 
    {     
        String filename = "CustomerList.txt";
        String cusid = txtCusId.getText();
        String cusFName = txtFName.getText();

        List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Read the lines of text into an ArrayList
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

            if(!input.ready()) { //check whether the file can be read
                throw new IOException();                    
            }

            String line = null;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) !=null) { //Read a line of Text
                if (line.contains(cusid)) {
                    aList.add(line);
                }
            }

            input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Remove the `input.ready()` check.  That method only checks whether the next read operation may block instead of returning immediately.